# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

This SQL

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(FOO)) over (PARTITION BY NULL) as bar`

causes the error

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions`

There doesnt seem to be any answers to solving this error on stackoverflow.

Comment: Just a note, `DISTINCT` is not a function. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT FOO)` to make code clearer!

Comment: @jarlh that was how the code was presented to me and after some tinkering with it, removing the parentheses doesn't solve the error, but noted for future questions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fixed

Change the SQL to `SELECT COUNT(FOO) over (PARTITION BY NULL) as bar`

Postgres doesnt like having DISTINCT after COUNT and will treat DISTINCT as a function, when there isn't one.

Comment: This "fixes" the error by changing the semantics. Unfortunately Postgresql does not allow count distinct inside window functions, as the error states. See https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/48d0cacb0907210532p7941a9f2i4f7b6bc7407b1131%40mail.gmail.com for a solution preserving the semantics.